# Swift - Scroll view back to first view - scrollViewDidScroll Is not called

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add to my code a loop page . When the scroll view get to the last page the next page should be the first and vice versa.

In my project I have a main storyboard with a view controller where a Scroll View is placed and two xib file containing the two pages.

Everything works as should be however I cannot figure out a way how to have an infinite scrolling in both ways (back and forward)

If I add the function scrollViewDidScroll it seems that its not called.

Any Idea?
This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set Scroll Bar Hidden
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false



        // Create the views used in the swipe container view
        let NewsPage :NewsViewController =  NewsViewController(nibName: "NewsViewController", bundle: nil);
        let MusicPage :MusicViewController =  MusicViewController(nibName: "MusicViewController", bundle: nil);


        // Add in each view to the container view hierarchy

        self.addChildViewController(MusicPage);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(MusicPage.view);
        MusicPage.didMoveToParentViewController(self);

        self.addChildViewController(NewsPage);
        self.scrollView!.addSubview(NewsPage.view);
        NewsPage.didMoveToParentViewController(self);


        // Set up the frames of the view controllers to align with eachother inside the container view

        var adminFrame :CGRect = NewsPage.view.frame;
        adminFrame.origin.x = adminFrame.width;
        MusicPage.view.frame = adminFrame;


        // Set the size of the scroll view that contains the frames

        let scrollWidth: CGFloat  = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        let scrollHeight: CGFloat  = self.view.frame.size.height
        self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth, scrollHeight);

        NSLog("%f",scrollHeight);
    }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > scrollView.frame.size.width){
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0.0,0.0), animated: false)
        }
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         NSLog("dragg");
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the scrollView's delegate? Try adding to viewDidLaod

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

Comment: thanks this is calling ViewDidScroll however, when I add scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true) the page just jumps to the first one instead of scrolling to it